How to handle "I want to begin with cryptography, but I don't know from where"-type questions?
Every now and then we have such questions from newcomers and this is a perfectly natural question for them.
I thought that if we have a central guide (either here on meta or on the main site) here, and maintain it, both sides will be happy, as we can close these question as duplicates / hopefully get less and the newcomers get their answers. In my opinion the combined answers to such a question should cover questions of the following style(s):

I just want to learn classical Cryptography
I just want to begin Cryptography
I want to learn side-channel Cryptography


Feel free to add/change my question.

We may already have such a question (whether we want to do this) on meta, but I couldn't find it. Also I think such a question should live actually on the main site (so we can close as a duplicate) which would make this question about whether we want such a question on the main site.

@SEJPM So, post on the main, wait for answers and close as off-topic that, too.

So, "wait for people to tell you here that you're not the only one wanting this and once that happened and got a couple of upvotes, post a question on the main site".

I suggest  to categorize the questions  into three levels : beginner , intermediate , advance tags  in order to clean and organize the posts.  it is just an idea.

What about each answer categorize the levels?

it could also be possible

I think this is a good idea. We should create a canonical post (or a few) on the main site for a few common questions. This is what Information Security does. Over there, we create a Meta question, as you did, to ask if a canonical question for a certain topic would be a good idea, and then make or modify a question on the main site to be the canonical question. Any new questions that ask the same thing can be marked as duplicate. This has the additional benefit of making it more likely that a new user, when typing up their question, will see the canonical question or a linked duplicate pop up as a suggestion for possible duplicates.
